# I need Prime font for my web site

Tags: css, font-family

My web designer told me to use prime regular font in my web site.

I didn't find it.

Any body know how to use the font prime.

```
body
{
 font-family: ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final result:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'primelight';
    src: url('prime_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('prime_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.svg#primelight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
    body { 
        font-family: "primelight", Verdana, Tahoma;
    }
    </style>
```

1. go to http://fontfabric.com/prime-free-font/
   and download the font
2. creat a repository in your website  :  fonts/prime/
3. put the prime files inside make sure you ve something like this :PrimeLight.otf

alternative :

1. download the font
2. convert it with all options @ http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: it's exacly what I'm looking for.