# installing new Fonts in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been attempting to install a font and use it in my CSS and have been unsuccessful at this. I would like to figure out where am I going wrong. I uploaded the .tff file in the same folder as the CSS file and added to the updated my css file in the appropriate manner.

here is a copy of what I have in my css:

```
    @font-face
    {
   font-family: ImpactLabel;
   src: url('ImpactLabel.tff');
    }
    p.change
    {
   font-family:ImpactLabel;
   color: #A70C1E;
   font-size:3em;   
    }
```

Here is my html file:

```
<p class="change">Text</p>
```

Comment: Check your font file path.

Comment: It's "ttf" (TrueType Font) not "tff". Check your browser's developer console for 404's on your font file(s) and fix the path(s) if you have any.

Comment: Download the full webfont kit from FontSquirrel and it will work across a lot more browsers: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Impact-Label

Comment: Are you doing this locally or on a server? if on an IIS, you need to specify the MIME type of the ttf and wof...

Comment: can u give an Fiddle link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this ->

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ImpactLabel;
  src: url('ImpactLabel.ttf'), <-- Check if the path is correct (ttf not tff)
       url('ImpactLabel.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

Then just call on your **class**:

```
.change {
  font-family: 'ImpactLabel';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'primelight';
    src: url('prime_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('prime_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('prime_light-webfont.svg#primelight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
    p.change{ 
        font-family: "primelight", Verdana, Tahoma;
    }
```

creat a repository in your website : fonts/prime/

put the prime files inside make sure you have something like this :PrimeLight.otf

read more here [I need Prime font for my web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679714/i-need-prime-font-for-my-web-site/18683537#18683537)

Answer (score 0):

Upload it to the [FontSquirrel Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and use the code and files it gives you.  Problem solved!

FontSquirrel will generate several different formats of the font which are loaded selectively by different browsers and devices (and thus will give you the broadest compatibility).

**Edit:** Apparently this font is actually on FontSquirrel already, so all you need to do is [click here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Impact-Label) and download the webfont kit from them.

Comment: note that the font must be legally able to be used in the web.

Comment: @jackJoe yep I just checked on that - this font is actually already available on FontSquirrel for free and it has a free license for all purposes.